# java mail api javax.mail.MessageException Connect failed pop3

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

I want to read mails from a user account using java mail api.

The mail server is a particular mail server:

ReadEMail.java - client

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
props.put("mail.pop3.port", port);
props.put("mail.pop3.user", username);
props.put("mail.pop3.timeout", "158000");
props.put("mail.pop3.connectiontimeout", "158000");
/*  Create the session and get the store for read the mail. */
session = Session.getInstance(props);
store = session.getStore("pop3");
session.setDebug(true);
store.connect(host,username, password);
```

The error message on the client side:

```
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.apop.enable: false

DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "localhost", port 4444, isSSL false
S: +OK  Mail Server Ready 
C: CAPA
S: 
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Unexpected response: 
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:210)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at com.mail.reader.MailReader.connect(MailReader.java:67)
    at com.mail.reader.TestMailReader.main(TestMailReader.java:21)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response: 
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.readResponse(Protocol.java:752)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.multilineCommand(Protocol.java:766)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.capa(Protocol.java:675)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:140)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:261)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:206)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Can you add "mail.debug" and "mail.debug.quote" to "true". Then post the protocol trace that
you'll see on System.out.

Comment: I tried to debug the client and server. On the server side everyting seems ok (i also tested the pop3 port with telnet and it works as expected). Using java mail api it seems that the client closes the connction before the server sends the reponse to the CAPA command.How to solve this?

Comment: Did you try "mail.debug.quote"?  It looks like the server is sending something unexpected, perhaps just a blank line that violates the protocol spec.  Setting "mail.debug.quote" will help us see exactly what the server is returning.  When using telnet, what does the server return when you enter the CAPA command?

Comment: it enters a list of commands that the server accepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it seems to complain about an unexpected response to CAPA, it might be that your mail server sends an non-standard response. You could try setting `mail.pop3.disablecapa` to true, so it won't send the CAPA.

As an aside `System.getProperties();` returns a shared Properties object, not sure if that's what you intented. Maybe do a `new Properties();` instead?